# MVC3 pass exception from controller to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

want to print the exception on cshtml page, but unbale to get where to use this

```
 @Html.ValidationSummary()
      <form method="post" action="AddUser">
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add error message in action like this.

```
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "error message.");
```

and use `@Html.ValidationSummary() in view.`

Comment: @Isha please upvote and accept this answer if this answer helps you, so people know this is the correct answer